# Is there any way to open a folder in vs code with just clicking the folder and use a shortcut? (windows11)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, directory, keyboard, shortcut

I want to click a folder and use a shortcut for open the folder in vs code instead of right click and select the "open in vs code". Is there any way to do this?

Comment: look into `Auto Hot Key`

Comment: Thank you! Solved thanks to the Auto Hot Key!